# Referencing AJAX MaskedEditExtender in code behind

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, maskededitextender

Found this code to dynamically create an AJAX MaskedEdit Textbox...

```
    Dim txt As New TextBox()
    txt.ID = "txt_name"
    Panel1.Controls.Add(txt)

    Dim mee As New MaskedEditExtender()
    mee.Mask = "999-999-9999"
    mee.MaskType = MaskedEditType.Number
    mee.InputDirection = MaskedEditInputDirection.LeftToRight
    mee.TargetControlID = "txt_name"
    Panel1.Controls.Add(mee)
```

and "ToolkitScriptManager" is properly referenced on my Master page.

Intellisense is not finding the "MaskedEditExtender", what do I have to include (VB.NET 2008) to properly reference it?

Answer (score 0):

TOO SIMPLE...

```
    Imports AjaxControlToolkit
```